# Adding a " to a string in code

Tags: java, android, json

I'm writing some code for web services for my Android app which uses JSON. The url should look like this

```
url = url + "?maddr=" + mailAddr + "&pwd=FB&lect=" + """ + lectName + """ + "&fb=Test";
```

This is because the Lectname may be two or more words. However the compiler wont accept """, is there a character I can precede the " with to get the compiler to accept it into my string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `" \" "`. You have to escape the `"`
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character
You need this in (nearly) every programming language.